# Upload file to google drive using php and retrieve the link

Tags: php, mysql, google-drive-api

I have a html form where there is a file upload button. Now what I want to do is select a file and submit the form, then the server should upload the file to google drive using php and retrieve the link of that file. Actually, I want to only upload image files. So, I would really appreciate it if anyone can show me how to upload the file to google drive using php and then retrieve the direct link to that image so that I can store the link to a mysql database.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Have you followed the [quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php)? They provide example code.

Comment: I tried, but failed to upload anything. And there is no example showing how to get the link of the uploaded file.

Comment: To upload file, you can use either [Simple](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#simple) or [Multipart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart) upload method. Use Simple Upload when the file is small enough to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails. Then, use Multipart Upload if you have metadata that you want to send along with the data to upload. Here is an [example](https://github.com/null-none/GoogleDrivePHP) and [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573965/google-drive-api-get-file-edit-url) to get the direct link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Google API Client https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

It will give you all the tools you need.